# Should unmodified components of an open source project be added to version control?

Tags: git, version-control

A team of developers decide to start a new (Java) software project that uses an open source project.

The developers clone the repository, creating a local repository of the open source project.

The team of developers modify only a few components of the open source project, perhaps for configuration purposes. A bulk of the team's work involves writing new components.

The developers must then create their own repository so they can work on the project.

Should the team's repo contain all code, including unmodified components of the open source project, or should it contain only new and modified components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb is to exclude files what are generated automatically during project import / build / etc.

If your team only writes new components, maybe better to create a template project only containing the configuration and what else necessary to start writing a component.